# webpack-web-server not starting while building custom data viz (getBuildableComponents issue)

Tags: webpack-dev-server, looker-studio

I'm trying to build a custom dataviz for data studio, but it starts at `npm run start` because of `TypeError: getBuildableComponents is not a function`

```
❯ node -v
v15.3.0
```

Anyone having this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: package.json:  https://pastebin.com/PTxPKjcn

Comment: trace : https://pastebin.com/UKuew7Nw

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: https://github.com/googledatastudio/tooling/issues/190#issuecomment-756893745 using the workaroud

Answer (score 0):

Bug opened on ds-components here : https://github.com/googledatastudio/tooling/issues/190